# Regex to get the currency from price - Typescript

Tags: regex, typescript, playwright

I have this price: $59.95 and I want to get the currency USD $ out of it with the help of RegEx.

This is what I have written so far (I am using Playwright Test and Typescript):

```
public async getCurrency(): Promise<string | undefined> {
    const price = await this.price.textContent();
    console.log('PRICE');
    console.log(price);
    const currency = price?.replace(/\\d+\\.\\d+/g, '');
    console.log('CURRENCY');
    console.log(currency);
    return currency;
  }
```

But the currency in the above log file is $59.95 instead of $.
The price is as expected - $59.95.
Can you help? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change your Regex to...

tip: Use trim to remove whitespace from border

```js
const price "$ 88.88"
const currency = price.replace(/\s*\d*[\.|\,]\d*\s*/, "").trim()
```

Comment: You don't have to escape the dot and comma in the character class, you can remove the pipe as it dot not mean OR, but it is a pipe char. Note that as all the quantifiers are optional, the pattern can also match just a single dot and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, sorry guys!
I just had to do this (note no double \):

```
const currency = price?.replace(/\d+\.\d+/g, '');
```